# Sugar.Date.isBetween() constantly produces false regardless of the dates

Tags: javascript

I am using Sugar 2.0.4 to more easily handle dates.  When I tried to run the following code snippet:

```
const now = new Sugar.Date(new Date().toDateString()); // as of this posting should be '7/3/2020'
const startDate = new Sugar.Date('8/14/2020');
const endDate = new Sugar.Date('8/16/2020');
if (now.isBetween(startDate, endDate)) {
   alert(`${startDate.medium()}, ${now.medium()}, ${endDate.medium} : ${now.isBetween(startDate, endDate)}`);
}
// I still see the alert popup, even though now.isBetween correctly returns false
```

I have tried with multiple start and end dates, include '7/3/2020' and '7/5/2020', which also produces false and still enters the conditional, popping up the alert.

Is there something I should be doing with my Sugar.Date objects prior to isBetween()? Please advise, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

SugarDate can use multiple forms - `default`, `chainable` or `extended` (see [usage](https://sugarjs.com/dates/#/Usage)). You were using `chainable` which returns a `Sugar.Date` object (which is always truthy). What you want is to use `extended` form like this:

```js
const now = new Sugar.Date(new Date().toDateString()); // as of this posting should be '7/3/2020'
const startDate = new Sugar.Date('8/14/2020');
const endDate = new Sugar.Date('8/16/2020');

// use extended form
if(Sugar.Date.isBetween(now,startDate,endDate)) {
  ...
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

`isBetween` returns a `Sugar.Date` object, so you'll need to call `valueOf()`. I admit, this feels funny, not sure if this is a bug or on purpose?

```js
if(now.isBetween(startDate,endDate).valueOf()) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: I tried both.  valueOf() still constantly returns false, while Sugar.Date.isBetween(now, startDate, endDate) returns the error "Cannot convert object to primitive value"

Comment: Ok, tried Sugar.Date.isBetween(now, startDate, endDate) and this also constantly returns false, even if startDate = '7/3/2020' and endDate = '7/5/2020', while now = '7/3/2020'.

Comment: @user1544358 - you're right, but it works when the dates are not instances of Sugar Date and just plain date objects. Check [this out](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-g7nio?file=/demo.js)

Comment: then are Sugar.Date comparators worth using?

Comment: Thanks, Adam! Your solution works! Using Sugar as extended instead of chainable works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my code to work using Sugar.Date.create() instead:

```
Sugar.extend();
const now = Sugar.Date.create(); // as of this posting should be '7/3/2020'
const startDate = Sugar.Date.create('7/3/2020');
const endDate = Sugar.Date.create('7/5/2020');

alert(now.isBetween(startDate, endDate));  // returns "true"
```

You extend the Date object using Sugar.extend(), then your Date objects have access to the Sugar Date methods and properties